Identify PID Parameter for a nonlinear Simulink System without an objective function
For a huge nonlinear Simulink system, I have to find optimal PID Parameter. It isn't possible to build the objective or the fitness function.
Do you know a alogirthm to identify optimal PID Parameter for that kind of problem?
I tried to implement Genetic Algorithm or particle swarm optimization. But these Algorithms assume a fitness function.

Consider linearizing your system (e.g. by first order taylor series). You would then be on much firmer ground theoretically, since PID controllers and algorithms on how to set the gains are much more researched on linear time-invariant systems.
